# Vampire book with white dress cover (showing bare feet)

Tags: story-identification, vampire

The book contained shapeshifters that could transform into animals that weren’t your usual picks. Like armadillos etc. The vampire who changed the main character had a type of control over her and her thoughts. The restaurant she worked at also had a vampire theme briefly I believe!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the ***[Tantalize](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42155-tantalize)*** series (2007-2012) by Cynthia Leitich Smith...?

According to the synopisis for the first book in the series, *[Tantalize](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10727734-tantalize)* (2007), the protagonist, Quincie Morris, opens a vampire-themed restaurant with her uncle and has a hybrid-werewolf first love.

> Quincie Morris has never felt more alone. Her parents are dead, and her hybrid-werewolf first love is threatening to embark on a rite of passage that will separate them forever. Then, as **she and her uncle are about to unveil their hot vampire-themed restaurant,** a brutal murder leaves them scrambling for a chef. Can Quincie transform their new hire into a culinary Dark Lord before opening night? Can he wow the crowd in his fake fangs, cheap cape, and red contact lenses - or is there more to this earnest face than meets the eye? As human and preternatural forces clash, a deadly love triangle forms, and the line between predator and prey begins to blur. Who's playing whom? And how long can Quincie play along before she loses everything? TANTALIZE marks Cynthia Leitich Smith's delicious debut as a preeminent author of dark fantasy.

A [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/291611911) notes that there are other supernatural entities in the book, such as were-armadillos, were-vultures, and principal-vampires.

> Modern vampire books make me wish Buffy was still on the air. Cynthia Leitich Smith enters the graphic novel realm by illustrating the story of one of her lead characters from a teen book series. The werewolf hybrid Kieren is torn between leaving home to meet his new pack, and a convoluted murder mystery surrounding the local Italian restaurant. Add in **were-creatures such as armadillos and vultures, scheming principal-vampires,** and a fighting mad English teacher, and you end up with this pot of lunacy. The only tantalizing thing about Smith's creation is the undying hope for a better story.

The synopsis for the third book, *[Blessed](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8601666-blessed)* (2011), notes that Quincie is now a neophyte vampire, having been blessed by a seductive vampire chef.

> You'll try to fight it. But you'll only be fighting your true self. It's done. It's destined. In time, you'll come to accept it. He pulled back his sleeve to reveal two dress watches. In time, you'll come to me.
>
> **Quincie P. Morris, teen restaurateuse and neophyte vampire,** is in the fight of her life -- or undeath. Even as she adjusts to her new appetites, she must clear her best friend and true love, the hybrid werewolf Kieren, of murder charges; thwart the apocalyptic ambitions of Bradley Sanguini, **the seductive vampire-chef who blessed her;** and keep her dead parents' restaurant up and running. She hires a more homespun chef and adds the preternaturally beautiful Zachary to her wait staff. But with hundreds of new vampires on the rise and Bradley off assuming the powers of Dracula Prime, Zachary soon reveals his true nature -- and a flaming sword -- and they hit the road to staunch the bloodshed before it's too late. Even if they save the world, will there be time left to salvage Quincie's soul?

The cover of the third book also shows the bottom of a flowing white dress.

[image: Cover of the book "Blessed" by Cynthia Leitich Smith.]

Comment: No bare feet...sounds close otherwise, though.  OP could have conflated it with another picture.

Comment: YES THIS IS IT! I guess I read the third book in the series thinking it was the first! Definitely got the bare feet part muddied in my memory. Thank you so much!!!